# jQuery autosuggest library that accepts pasting multiple, comma-separated values and auto selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've tried multiple jQuery autosuggest plugins, but couldn't find what I need. That would. be, provide a dataset to an input box, and then paste multiple comma-separated values as a list. After that, all those matching values should be automatically selected. Is there something like that pre-made?